# Dereferencing a *const Mutex panics

Tags: rust, unsafe

I am currently working on a safe binding of a FFI library, and this is a minimal implementation of the problem I have encountered.

```rust
fn test_weird_thing() {
    use std::sync::Mutex;
                
    struct WeirdThing<'a> {
        vec: Mutex<Vec<i32>>,
        callback_runner: &'a CallbackRunner,
    }

    // Hypothetical FFI Struct///
    struct CallbackRunner {
        callback: extern "C" fn(*const Mutex<Vec<i32>>),
        data: *const Mutex<Vec<i32>>,
    }

    impl CallbackRunner {
        extern "C" fn default_callback(_vec: *const Mutex<Vec<i32>>) {}

        fn new() -> Self {
            CallbackRunner {
                callback: Self::default_callback,
                data: std::ptr::null(),
            }
        }

        fn set_callback(
            &mut self, callback: extern "C" fn(*const Mutex<Vec<i32>>), 
            data: *const Mutex<Vec<i32>>
        ) { 
            self.data = data;
            self.callback = callback;
        }

        fn run(&self) {
            (self.callback)(self.data);
        }
    }
    /////////////////////////////

    impl<'a> WeirdThing<'a> {
        fn new(runner: &'a mut CallbackRunner) -> Self {
            let vec = Mutex::new(Vec::new());
            runner.set_callback(Self::callback, &vec as *const Mutex<Vec<i32>>);
            WeirdThing { vec, callback_runner: runner }
        }

        extern "C" fn callback(vec: *const Mutex<Vec<i32>>) {
            let vec = unsafe { &*vec };
            let mut vec = vec.lock().unwrap();
            vec.push(1);
        }

        fn do_thing(&self) -> Vec<i32> {
            self.callback_runner.run();
            self.vec.lock().unwrap().clone()
        }
    }

    let mut runner = CallbackRunner::new();
    let thing = WeirdThing::new(&mut runner);
    debug!("Thing: {:?}", thing.do_thing());
}
```

I have thought that `thing.vec` should be valid when `runner.run()` is called, since it is called when `thing` is still alive, but the code panics.

How should I explain this behavior?

Comment: Executing the example on [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a120e6650426ad0df6400288523562e4) under Tools/Miri immediately points to the source of Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Actually looking at it again it cold be a duplicate, does this answer your question? [What is this weird behavior when using unsafe and pointers in constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77074856/442760)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thing` **is** valid when you call the callback, the problem is that both adding `vec` to the struct as well as returning it from the function does **move** it, in other words it can be at another memory location than the one `callback_runner.data` points to.

Since you're dereferencing a dangling pointer your code contains UB, lucky for you you got an error instead of a silent failure somewhen down the line.

To get around that you have to make sure `vec` isn't moved around in memory after you create the pointer to it, for example by putting it on the heap with a (pinned) `Box`.

I've lined out [in this answer how to create a pointer to something you create within the function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77074876/442760) you should be able to apply it to your problem.